# How to solve $b^x$=$\log_bx$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms

I was looking through YouTube when I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMfOsKWryS4) video by blackpenredpen. The question was$$\text{Solve: }b^x=\log_bx$$which I thought I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving it:$$b^x=\log_bx$$

$$b^{(b^x)}=\require{\cancel}{b^{(\log_bx)}}$$

$$b^{(b^x)}=x$$$$\color{green}{b^x}\ln(b^{\cancel{(b^x)}})=\ln(x)$$$$\color{green}{x}\ln(b\ln(b))=\ln(\ln(x))$$$$\frac{\cancel{x}\ln(b\ln(b))}{\cancel{x}}=\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{x}$$$$e^{\cancel{\ln}(b\ln(b))}=\sqrt[x]{\ln(x)}$$$$b\ln(b)=e^{\sqrt[x]{\ln(x)}}$$$$\implies\cancel{e}^{\cancel{\ln}(b)}=e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}$$$$b=\sqrt[x]{x}$$$$\therefore x=b^x$$

#### **My question**

---

Is my solution correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution more easily?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "solve". In your solution, you have $x$ on both the left hand side and right hand side. Are you trying to express $x$ as a function of $b$?

Comment: @Godfather Yes, I am trying to express $x$ as a function of $b$

Comment: There is an error. Note that $\ln(b^x\ln b)\not=x\ln(b\ln b)$.

Comment: Could you stop putting `$$\color{white}{\require{cancel}{.}}$$` at the top of each one of your posts? It flashes up each time during the TeX processing phase, and is getting a bit irritating. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Sorry about that, I'll stop doing that

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Please, avoid chitchatting in your posts. See [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#31696).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $y=b^x$ and $y=\log_b x$ are inversed function to each other, so they are mirror symmetric with respect the straight line $y=x$. All intersection points of the two curves $y=b^x$ and $y=\log_b x$ must lie on the straight line $y=x$. So we immediately have

$$b^x=x$$

Comment: Which can be written $$x=\frac{W\left(-\ln\left(b\right)\right)}{-\ln\left(b\right)}$$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: Yes, the W function.

Comment: Your argument is flawed.  For example, $y = (15 - x^3)/7$ and $y = (15 - 7 x)^{1/3}$ are inverses of each other,  but the two curves intersect at $x=1, y=2$ and $x=2, y=1$ as well as at a point on the diagonal.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this argument only works for this special case, may not work in general. @RobertIsrael

Comment: It works because (for $b > 1$) $b^x$ is strictly convex and $\log_{b}(x)$ is strictly concave, thus their graphs can't intersect in more than two points.  But if there was
an intersection $(a,b)$ off the diagonal, say with $a < b$, there would be at least three:
$(a,b)$, $(b,a)$ and by the Intermediate Value Theorem some point $(c,c)$ on the diagonal  with $a < c < b$.